# Trying to preventDefault .on() everything but input in document

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, preventdefault

I have some code like this:

```
$(document).on("keydown", ":not(input)", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 8) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Everything is working fine except the `:not(input)` selector. I can't backspace in any input box.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain exactly why it's happening this way, it's likely due to the way the event propagates up the dom, however, removing the delegation and using an `event.target` check seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/7KDMn/3/

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(event) {
    if ( event.which === 8 && !$(event.target).is("input") ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: This did the trick, but I'm left wondering why my original code didn't work. :(